# prove that $n$ is prime or $n=4$ when $n|4((n−1)!+1)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

Let $n \gt 1$ be an integer such that :

$n|4((n-1)!+1)$

Prove that
$n=4$ or $n$ is prime

Comment: you should include your attempt

Comment: See [Wilson's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem).

Answer (score -1):

Since $4((n-1)!+1)$ has an explicit factor of $4$, plainly $2,4$ divide it, noting that $2$ is a prime. If $n\ne 2,4$ then $n|4((n-1)!+1)$ is true when $n|((n-1)!+1)$. Another way of saying that is $((n-1)!+1) \equiv 0 \bmod n$

If $n$ is prime, Wilson's theorem tells us that $(n-1)! \equiv -1 \bmod n$, which would imply the desired result $((n-1)!+1) \equiv 0 \bmod n$

It remains to be shown that if $n$ is not prime, the proposition fails. If $n>4$ is not prime, it is factorable: $n=ab$ where $2\le a,b \le \frac{n}{2}<n-1$. Since both $a,b$ are factors that appear in the factorial product $(n-1)!$, it is the case that $n\mid(n-1)!$ hence $n\not \mid((n-1)!+1)$ and we are done.

Comment: Please strive not to post yet more dupe answers to FAQs. There is an error in the  argument. See the linked dupe for correct proofs. Best to delete it so the dupe will automatically be cleaned up by the system.